# Create iterator to return elements from each iterable one by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I was learning the itertools module and I am trying to make an iterator to return each element from the iterables provided as input.

```
Agruments   Results
p, q, …     p0, q0, … plast, qlast
```

with one more rider that if say the lists are not of the same length then `next(it)` should return elements from the longer list when the shorter one runs out.

Attempt at solution

```
import itertools
l1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2=['a','b','c','d']
l=[]
for x,y in itertools.zip_longest(l1,l2):
    l.extend([x,y])
it=iter(x for x in l if x is not None)
```

Which kind of solves my problem

```
print(list(it))
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 5, 6]
```

Is there an easier or better way to do this? I searched for a solution on SO and was not able to get one.

Comment: The `itertools` documentation includes an implementation of this in the [Recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) section, called `roundrobin`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the sequence, and use a generator expression to filter out the `None` values:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

it = (v for v in chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(l1, l2)) if v is not None)
```

Rather than use `None` as the sentinel value, you may want to use a dedicated sentinel so you can use `None` in the input list:

```
_sentinel = object()
flattened = chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=_sentinel))
it = (v for v in flattened if v is not _sentinel)
```

If you want to filter out [*falsey* values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth), then you can also use [`filter(None, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
it = filter(None, chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(l1, l2)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, zip_longest
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> it = (v for v in chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(l1, l2)) if v is not None)
>>> list(it)
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 5, 6]
```

and with a local sentinel:

```
>>> l1 = [1, None, 2, None, 3, None]
>>> l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> _sentinel = object()
>>> flattened = chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=_sentinel))
>>> it = (v for v in flattened if v is not _sentinel)
>>> list(it)
[1, 'a', None, 'b', 2, 'c', None, 'd', 3, None]
```

The [`itertools` recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) also has:

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a modified version of your code, building a generator from the start (no storing list `l`):

```
import itertools
l1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2=['a','b','c','d']

def flat_zip(l1,l2):
    for x,y in itertools.zip_longest(l1,l2):
        if x:
            yield x
        if y:
            yield y
it=flat_zip(l1,l2)
```

Though I advise for using the builtin solutions above.

Answer (score 0):

Using only list comprehension.
Explanation in comments.
Adding only for variation.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
B = ["A", "B", "C"]

# zipping equal length 
flattened_zip_list = [item for sublist in zip(A, B) for item in sublist]

print(flattened_zip_list )

# leftover from longest list 
extra_list = [A[index] for index in range(min(len(A), len(B)), max(len(A), len(B)) if len(A) > len(B) else B[index])]

print(extra_list)

# final list 
flattened_zip_list.extend(extra_list)

print(flattened_zip_list)
```

Outputs

```
[1, 'A', 2, 'B', 3, 'C'] # after zipping same lengths 
[4, 5, 6] # leftover values 
[1, 'A', 2, 'B', 3, 'C', 4, 5, 6] # [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 5, 6], the one mentioned in question 

[Program finished]
```